# Why doesn't Lord Death die even though Death the Kid connects all three Lines of Sanzu?

Tags: soul-eater

In the second to last episode of the *Soul Eater* anime, Death the Kid connects all three Lines of Sanzu. According to the lore, the Lines of Sanzu only connect when a person is ready to become the next Grim Reaper.  Since only one Grim Reaper can exist at a time, this usually means the current Reaper drops dead immediately.  There came a crack in Lord Death's mask when Kid did it, but he survived.

Why, then, doesn't Lord Death die? Is it because Kid only *unconsciously* connected the lines?

Comment: Didn't the anime end before the manga? That would mean that the anime created its own ending independently of the manga. I do recall Death dying in the manga too, which means if that stuff is true, its all on the anime ending early, and writing its own semi arbitrary, partially deus ex machina, and generally low quality ending which would basically be filler. We all know filler regularly breaks continuity.